# Angular build fails with command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install, angular10

I don't really know why, but when i build my app using my ci/cd on Gitlab it fails with the error stack hereinafter.

On my computer i don't have an npm install issue.
Locally I have `node: 16.13.2 and npm 8.1.2`

On Gitlab for the ci/cd the image we use has `node: 'v16.13.1' and npm: '8.1.3'`

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-linux-x64-musl --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info build requesting source compile
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.7 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.1/node-v16.13.1-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.1/node-v16.13.1-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.1/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.1/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.109+
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-linux-x64-musl" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-linux-x64-musl --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.109+
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /builds/gara-project/gara-front-end/gara-console/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-25T15_43_04_463Z-debug.log
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I tried a lot of solutions found on internet `npm install --build-from-source` or add it in `package.json` but most of them seems not working